# Hard Disk Not Detected Only When Restarting Windows 10

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, grub

I have ran into an issue that I'm having trouble Googling my way out of. To summarize what has happened:

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 (Windows was already installed). I have made sure all the important steps (set to AHCI, Secure Boot Off, etc.) have been performed before installing Ubuntu.

Now, as mentioned in the guide I was following to perform a correct dual boot installation, GRUB launches upon PC start and gives me the option to boot into Ubuntu or Windows.

Everything works fine except for the fact that whenever I reboot Windows, it does not launch GRUB, but instead goes into Dell SupportAssist and says that no hard disk have been detected. When I shut down and boot the PC, GRUB launches as expected. Hence, the error is only related to when I click on restart in Windows.

My computer is a Dell XPS 13 9360.

Thank you very much for any help!

EDIT 1: Following @K7AAY comment, it works fine (GRUB welcomes me) when I hold SHIFT and click Shut Down.

Comment: Please boot into Windows, then click on the Windows START icon at bottom left. Hold down {SHIFT} and while holding it down, choose Shut Down. Then, power back up; are you able to choose Ubuntu and boot into Ubuntu? Please advise by clicking [edit] and tell us what happened.

Comment: You might also try turning off fast-quick boot in the bios (if available) to see if that makes a difference,

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution that fixed the problem I was having.

I simply had to update the firmware for the SSD in order to fix the problem.

Hopefully, this will be helpful in the future.